# Are you able to incorporate 'WebBrowser' in an .aspx using Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio

I am relatively new to codingand I am creating a website and I want to import google maps, as I plan to show parts of the local area. Long story short, I have googled how and Microsoft tells me to do this:

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]
[System.Windows.Forms.Docking(System.Windows.Forms.DockingBehavior.AutoDock)]
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ClassInterface(System.Runtime.InteropServices.ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)]
public class WebBrowser : System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserBase

However for some reason the code comes up as white for me (maybe because .aspx uses html I don't know). The first thing I tried to do (as an amateur) was to look for 'WebBrowser' in the toolbox but I couldn't see it. I am yet to find any video that helps with this and was hoping someone could offer me some advice.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: You should look at Google's doc's about their Maps.

Comment: short answer: no you can't. You should read more about how html and browser works in general. Then look at how aspx handles the client-server model. What you are looking for is an `iframe`. I would recommend you to read more tutorials for at least a week before you start.

Comment: Ok, thank you for responding.